# How is the size of a string allocated in ROS2 idl?

Tags: ros, ros2, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How is the size of a string dynamically allocated while converting msg to idl. Is there a possibility to limit this size ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299305/how-is-the-size-of-a-string-allocated-in-ros2-idl-?/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a duplicate of your previous question: https://answers.ros.org/question/299297/maximum-limit-of-string-in-ros2/

To see how to define bounded strings in ROS2 you can refer to the [Interface Definition design document](http://design.ros2.org/articles/interface_definition.html):

`a string with an upper boundary: string<=N to limit the length of the string to N characters`

An example of message definition using bounded strings is available [here](https://github.com/ros2/rosidl_python/blob/183f19b3eb7a99d70443ea9bd2893beee417d03c/rosidl_generator_py/msg/Strings.msg#L7)

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2018-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0